# WCF, DLLIMPORT strange issues

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, iis-7, hosting, dllimport

I have a very strange issue that i cannot figure out.

First i have a WCF service 4.0 done in VS2010.
the service have couple methods that return string array, datatable and such.
some of them use function from C++ dll throught [dllimport]

i made a test console to test everything. when i run the WCF from visual studio and use the generated path it works wonderfully.

now here is where it become strange. if i open my local IIS create a new application and point to my VS source code the WCF i can see it perfectly.

now using the http path from IIS local instead i refresh the methods all seems correct. But when i run my test app i can call any unction without any problem EXCEPT anyone using DLLIMPORT functions. they ALL crash and cannot trace even by tracing CES exceptions.

Doing line by line logging show that the exception is really on the call of those functions

the DLL in question is the same and the path is hardcoded for my computer since still in test phase and the folder is c:\DLL\mylib.DLL so nothing to do with shadow copy IIS/visual studio do when you actually run. also DLL reference by name withotu path even if it's in sys32 doesnt work.

Any clue ?

also. 32bit, changing app pool level right access on folder, full admin on machine already too. all tried but unsuccessful.

Edit: adding to all that since i haven't made this clear, it's not my first WCF real setup. i've already made alot of services before and deployed them myself (probably somewhere around 50-60 services). I am asking because i have never seen this issue before and i tried all tricks i knew and could find on the internet and resource people i know.

We have decided to incorporate the whole service in the WPF project locally since it work as long as IIS is not hosting. but this is really not a good thing as this data and work should NOT be done on client side but instead on server side. Right now it's fine since the software that need to use this is not released to public yet so it isn't critical.

Next option will be net TCP/IP windows service hosted on the web server if i don't find anything else.

Comment: Does the account on which the app runs (not just the app pool) have full access on the folder where the DLL is located? Also, if you move the DLL to the same place where the WCF DLL is located, does it change the outcome?

Comment: I have not played with any user on my developpement machine and it's running asp.net under the Iuser account like by default and he does have access to the folder. also to make sure i also added "Full control" right to the account "Everyone" for testing purpose only obviously but no result.

Comment: Also the DLL aside the WCF DLL in the bin doesn't help. Even if the DLL path in the Import funtion doesn't specify a path. like example below

'[DllImport(@"MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int SET_XML_PATH([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]ref string path_PAnsiChar);'

also ading the file to copy to directory within the project doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go trough the trouble of having to hard code the logic in the main software and get away from web services for this issue. we will have to deal with updating, installing unregister and re register unmanaged DLL by hand somehow but at least it works.

we have added over 5 web services since that happen and no problem with them but again none of them use DLL imports.